# ArgoCD - what need be done after build a new image

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, cicd, argocd, gitops

I have deployed the application via ArgoCD successfully, and I can access it via its ingress url

The applicaiton uses the image name with latest tag, such as

```
image: <private_registry>/app_1_service:latest
```

I also manage other tags on same of tag `latest`, such as `image:<commit_id> or image:<1.0.xxx>`

Now, developers will update the codes, after commit changes, a gitlab pipeline  autoamtically runs and build a new image and override to tag `latest` with other tags and push to private docker registry

So what's the next step in ArgoCD?

How argocd know the application is changed, and need be redeployed, and the `image:latest` need be pull again?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [ArgoCD image-updater](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

But before using the the image-updater, you need to install and set appropriate permission

```bash
helm repo add argo https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
helm install argocd-image-updater argo/argocd-image-updater
```

Once image-updator is up and running, then you need to set a few **annotations in the Argocd application**, as the update workers on different strategies

> **semver** - Update to the latest version of an image considering semantic versioning constraints
> **latest** - Update to the most recently built image found in a registry
> **digest** - Update to the latest version of a given version (tag), using the tag's SHA digest
> **name** - Sorts tags alphabetically and update to the one with the highest cardinality

`latest` strategies working awesome with tagging under some regex and `digest` more suited for testing environment.

[update-strategies](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics/update-strategies/)

You can also pull the private image from gitlab as well.

Here is the working example with helm-release

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  annotations:
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.allow-tags: 'regexp:^1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.[0-9]+$'
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.force-update: 'true'
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.pull-secret: 'pullsecret:develop-namespace/develop-app-gitlab-secrets'
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.update-strategy: latest
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: >-
      image-alias=registry.gitlab.com/myorg/my-test-image
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: develop-platform
  name: develop-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: develop-app
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
  project: develop-app-west6-b
  source:
    helm:
      releaseName: develop-app
      valueFiles:
        - develop-platform/values.yaml
    path: helm-chart/helm-chart
    repoURL: 'https://gitlab.com/my-org/develop-app.git'
    targetRevision: staging
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
```

If you need `digest` or just a latest then remove this

```
  argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.allow-tags: 'regexp:^1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.[0-9]+$'
```

this is working base on [regex](https://regexr.com/).
so in your case `<1.0.xxx>`

it can be `'regexp:^1.0.[0-9]+$'`

If everything configured properly and image updater working fine then you should be able to see logs image updater logs like this

```
time="2022-04-27T15:18:36Z" level=info msg="Successfully updated image 'registry.gitlab.com/test-image:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.115' to 'registry.gitlab.com/test-image:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.118'
```

Comment: image update and app sync are two different thing, you need image update,r not the sync which mentioned in the other comment. sync will sync the helm-chart manifest not the image.

Comment: ArgoCD image-updater doesn't work (at least for me), I followed the documentation, annotations, tag names, etc. It simply doesn't do anything. Their documentation is also bad. I had to create my own controller to roll out updates.

Comment: The whole idea is that when my CI pipeline runs, I want all pods to be updated! Argo can't do this. And I think annotating applications for this is seriously stupid (why? I just wanna updated to the latest tag!). So the working way is to periodically get the `Application` kind in the argocd namesapce, get the repo and then check for updates. If there is an update, then roll out restart the deployment!

Comment: it should but if the annotation is properly set plus you do not own controller, argocd can just update the image as well. but that need helm-chart, here is working example https://github.com/adiii717/argocd-demo-app

Answer (score 4):

If you are using latest tag, the most simple way is this

- set your k8s yaml `imagePullPolicy` to `Always`
- add below step in `gitlab-ci.yml` to restart application by calling argocd api

```yaml
argocd-restart:
    image: argoproj/argocd
    stage: deploy
    variables:
      GIT_STRATEGY: none
      ARGOCD_SERVER: "192.111.111.111:30000"
      # gitlab admin panel variable
      # ARGOCD_USERNAME: "admin"
      # ARGOCD_PASSWORD: "XXXXXX"
    before_script:
      - echo "ARGOCD_SERVER:$ARGOCD_SERVER"
      - echo "ARGOCD_APP_NAME:$ARGOCD_APP_NAME"
      - echo "ARGOCD_USERNAME:$ARGOCD_USERNAME"
    script:
      - argocd login "${ARGOCD_SERVER}" --insecure --username "${ARGOCD_USERNAME}" --password "${ARGOCD_PASSWORD}"
      - argocd app actions run "$ARGOCD_APP_NAME" restart --kind Deployment |& tee response.txt
      - cat response.txt
      # if response.txt have content, exit with error, empty response means success
      - if [ -s response.txt ]; then exit 1; fi
    only:
      - master
      - dev
```

argocd cli doc: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/commands/argocd_app_actions_run/

Above solution is not suit for production, because

- `imagePullPolicy: Always` means k8s always need to connect registry
- download image everytime when restart is waste of resource
- don't have version control

so for stg and prod, i do this.
Create a helm value file only for image tag such as `stg-image-tag.yaml`.

```yaml
image:
  tag: "stg-v0.0.1"
```

Add this file to argocd app config
[image]

Modify gitlab-ci.yml, build image with new image tag, and commit the image tag to `stg-image-tag.yaml`

- i use $CI_PIPELINE_IID as version number in image tag.
- i have branch name for each env

```yaml
docker-build:
  image: docker
  stage: build
  variables:
    # REGISTRY_SERVER: 192.168.111.111
    # REGISTRY_USER: xxx
    # REGISTRY_PASSWORD: xxx
  before_script:
    - IMAGE_TAG="$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-v0.0.$CI_PIPELINE_IID"
  script:
    - docker login -u "$REGISTRY_USER" -p "$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $REGISTRY_SERVER
    - docker build .
      -t "$NEW_IMAGE_REPO:latest"
      -t "$NEW_IMAGE_REPO:$IMAGE_TAG"
    - docker push "$NEW_IMAGE_REPO" --all-tags
    - echo IMAGE_TAG=$IMAGE_TAG >> IMAGE_TAG.env
    - cat IMAGE_TAG.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      # add IMAGE_TAG to other jobs as env var
      dotenv: IMAGE_TAG.env
    expire_in: "86400" # 1 day

commit-image-tag:
  image: curlimages/curl
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - job: docker-build
      artifacts: true
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    GITLAB_PROJECT_ID: "111"
    GITLAB_PROJECT_TOKEN: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  before_script:
    - echo "IMAGE_TAG:$IMAGE_TAG"
  script:
    - |
      cat <<EOF > body.txt
      {
        "branch":"master",
        "commit_message":"update image tag ${IMAGE_TAG}",
        "actions":[
          {
            "action":"update",
            "file_path":"helm-charts/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-image-tag.yaml",
            "content":"image:\n  tag: $IMAGE_TAG"
          }
        ]
      }
      EOF
    - |
      cat <<EOF > header.txt
      Authorization: Bearer ${GITLAB_PROJECT_TOKEN}
      Content-Type: application/json
      EOF
    - curl --insecure "${CI_SERVER_URL}/api/v4/projects/${GITLAB_PROJECT_ID}/repository/commits" 
      -i --output response.txt
      --header @header.txt --data @body.txt
      --silent --write-out "%{response_code}" > response_code.txt
    - cat response.txt
    # error if response code is not 201
    - if [ "$(cat response_code.txt)" != "201" ]; then exit 1; fi
  only:
    - stg
    - prod
```

Then you setup a webhook so argocd will refresh image tag immediately.
otherwise argocd will refresh every 3 min.
[image]

Comment: that's cood, so if I want to do rolling update `kubectl rollout restart`, can I run with `argocd app` as well? any command for me to reference? and it supports to update image with `latest`?

Comment: basically this command `argocd app actions run "$ARGOCD_APP_NAME" restart --kind Deployment` is running `kubectl rollout restart deployment xxx`.
if you set `imagePullPolicy` to `Always`, k8s will download image from registry every time. it dosen't have to be `latest`, could be any tag.

Comment: one more question. This is suitable if the application has been deployed by argocd, right? If I run the first time,  it is failed. Any suggestion?

Comment: yes, you need to manually add app to argocd first.

Comment: thanks for the codes. Regarding the build stage, take a look about [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko), it does "docker login, build, tags, and push" together with one command. simplify a lot for your pipeline

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but looks like it will take a lot of effort to handle cache combine with gitlab runner. No, thank you. Currently i just use docker daemon in my gitlab server. Simple and easy.

Comment: well, actually the most important part of using argocd is pull mechanism. So if somehow if I need to reach CD server that should not be the best practice. If I can reach ArgoCD then I can run my terraform infrastructure scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

ArgoCD supports 2 types of application syncing policies:

1. manual: a user will login into the dashboard and update the image/chart version
2. automatic: ArgoCD will poll the container registry at fixed interval (e.g 3 min) and check if a new image's/chart's version is available based on a pattern. You can use regex to specify the image pattern. Argo will compare the current version with the new one.

[image: Auto sync option in ArgoCD dashboard]

Here's an example of deploying helm from Jfrog artifact registry automatically:

```
project: default
source:
  repoURL: 'https://abc.jfrog.io/artifactory/helm'
  targetRevision: '*.*.*' # set your regex pattern here
  helm:
    parameters:
      - name: image.tag
        env: dev
  chart: frontend-chart
destination:
  server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
  namespace: default
syncPolicy:
  automated: {} # enables auto syncing
```

Comment: regarding `ArgoCD will poll the container registry at fixed interval (e.g 3 min) and check if a new image's/chart's version is available based on a pattern`, will it apply to tag `latest` as well? if it found the SHA is changed and do the update automatically?

Comment: In my example it won't work since Jfrog (at least the way i use it) stores the name and version of the artifact (chart, image) only so ArgoCD will only detect change if the version or name is changed. If you set your Git repo as source instead of some 3rd party registry, then I believe the SHA based change will be detected. Check the last section of this [official doc](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/auto_sync/#:~:text=Argo%20CD%20has%20the%20ability,server%20to%20perform%20the%20deployment.)

Comment: ArgoCD will only detect new *chart-versions* though. If the chart stays the same and only the image is updated (e.g. a new "latest" version is uploaded to the image registry), ArgoCD will not update the deployment

Comment: Argo watches git repo only and not the image registry. There's no way you can watch achieve this without third-party plugins.