# Deploy through ArgoCD with same image name and tag ( image:latest )

Tags: docker, kubernetes, manifest, argocd, gitops

I have started to learn GitOps ArgoCD. I have one basic doubt. I am unable to test ArgoCD because I do not have any Cluster. It will be so kind of you if you can clear my doubts.

1. As an example currently I am running my deployment using `test:1` docker image. Then using Jenkins I upload `test:2` and then put `test:2` in place of `test:1` then ArgoCD detects the change and applies the new image in a cluster.
   But if before I used `test:latest` then using Jenkins I uploads a new image with same name `test:latest`. What will happen now? Will ArgoCD deploy the image ( name and tag of the new and previous image are the same )

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time (especially, it's not obvious to me what "sync pod with GitHub repo" means).  My expectation is that, if you build your images tagged `...:latest`, a Kubernetes redeploy will do nothing: the Deployment wants a matching Pod with an image named `...:latest`, which already exists, so it's untouched, and the Node needs an image named `...:latest`, which also already exists, so it's used as-is, and your cluster is using the old code and not the new.

Comment: Thanks, So you mean if we use same image name will name tag then ArgoCD will be unable to detect that..and will not deploy new code...Am I right?

Comment: That would be the behavior I'd expect from Kubernetes.  ArgoCD may have a way to force a restart, but it still wouldn't necessarily work reliably in a multi-node environment.

Comment: I have similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73617541/2854252

Answer (score 1):

If you need automation, you can consider [**Argo CD Image Updater**](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which does include in its [update strategies](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/update-strategies/):

`latest/newest-build` - Update to the most recently built image found in a registry

> It is important to understand, that this strategy will consider the build date of the image, and not the date of when the image was tagged or pushed to the registry.
>
> If you are tagging the same image with multiple tags, these tags will have the same build date.
> In this case, Argo CD Image Updater will sort the tag names lexically descending and pick the last tag name of that list.
>
> For example, consider an image that was tagged with the `f33bacd`, `dev` and `latest` tags.
> You might want to have the `f33bacd` tag set for your application, but Image Updater will pick the `latest` tag name.

```yaml
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: myimage=some/image
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/myimage.update-strategy: latest
```

Comment: Please note that ArgoCD Image Updater is not considered production-ready by its own [docs](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
I have yet to find a production ready solution for that problem....if anybody has a suggestion...?

Comment: @asturm Good point. I did not find a production ready solution either.